# What are origins of the 'ethnicities' on Xandar?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, aliens, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

An obvious feature of Xandar, while watching the movie Guardians of the Galaxy, is the diversity of 'ethnicities' (for want of a better term) on Xandar.

Examples are yellow, red, brown, white skinned, and one with cat like eyes in the Nova Corp, when they were linking up.

**Is the great diversity of 'ethnicities' on Xandar representative of groups indigenous to the planet, or from the allied planets in the Xandar Empire?**

Comment: I don't know if there is want of a better term. "Races" or "species" would work fine.

Comment: Who cares?! Racist...

Comment: Space racist. The worst kind.

Comment: How about a *Space-ist*? (Back to my cave)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is based from the [MCU](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_Wiki) and **NOT** the [Marvel comic Database](http://marvel.wikia.com/Main_Page) as specified in the question wich is based on The Guardian of The Galaxy movie.

[The Nova Empire](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Nova_Empire) is an intergalactic hegemony made up of multiple alien species that maintains a strict but benevolently personified rule over a good portion of the galaxy. While the Empire is made up of various alien races, it is ruled primarily by the ***Xandarians***. Other races known to inhabit the government are the ***Krylorians*** and the ***Rainers***. The Nova Corps is the Empire's primary military and peacekeeping force.

[image]

[Xandarians](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Xandarians) are ***humanoid and appear to resemble the human race perfectly*** (aside from many of them having abnormal eye colors not known for humans), at least externally. One marked distinction from humans is that Xandarian blood does not carry oxygen, so it is not red like human blood, but rather a bluish-purple hue.

[image]

[Krylorians](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Krylorians) are a Human-like race whose physical features are almost entirely similar to that of a Human. The only difference is their pink skin pigments and eye colors, which are much brighter than a Human's. They also have scar-like ridges on their face, but where on their face is indeterminable.
Krylorians are capable of procreating with other species, such as Xandarians.
[image]

[Rainers](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Rainers) are bipedal beings with a human-like body structure, but physical similarities between them and humans end there. The Rainers have brown wrinkly skin, pointy ears, four fingers, and cybernetic scalp implants in the place of hair.

[image]

**So in the MCU the Xandarians are skin color just like anyone on earth but many of them have abnormal eye colors not known for humans and their blood is not red, it is rather a bluish-purple hue. All the other races are part of the Nova Empire or simply tourist or merchant**

Merchant just like [The Broker](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Broker) who was a merchant who worked on Xandar and agreed to buy the Orb from the Ravagers.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty certain the yellow guys that you occasionally see in that background in Xandar are Astrans. I'm not too sure because they don't seem to have the typical massive heads of the Astran race but they are yellow, bald and humanoid so it seems feasible.

Here is the Wiki description of the Astrans:

> A **humanoid race** with **yellow skin** and toe-less, flat feet, **no hair**, four lungs, and special glands in the stomach.

And here is a picture of the yellow aliens I believe you are referring to:

[image]